# How to display text over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display text over image. Whenever someone hover mouse over the image.

My Div block is:

```
<div class="MainDIV">
<br><br><br>
<div class="popular_stores"  align="center">

    <span style="font-size: 12pt;">Browse our list of stores that we have coupons, coupon codes, and promo codes for.
    </span>
    <br>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR31R-rZO7MBzgGMrZlpa7C0-tx3CmzVz6pha7kt8Fw6PjpsMGENg" style="width: 100px;height: 50px;" >
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR31R-rZO7MBzgGMrZlpa7C0-tx3CmzVz6pha7kt8Fw6PjpsMGENg" style="width: 100px;height: 50px;" >
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR31R-rZO7MBzgGMrZlpa7C0-tx3CmzVz6pha7kt8Fw6PjpsMGENg" style="width: 100px;height: 50px;" >
    </li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

And rest of the CSS and JavaScript Function is:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$('.drama').mouseover(function(){
    alert("dss");
    var tt = $(this).parent().find('.toolTip');
    tt.html($(this).attr('title'));
    tt.show();
});
$('.drama').mouseout(function(){
    var tt = $(this).parent().find('.toolTip');
    tt.hide();
});

</script> 


<style type="text/css">

body {
    text-align: center;
    }

.MainDIV{
    padding:0;
    width:700px;    
    display: inline-block;  
    background-color:white;
    }

.MainDIV ul
{ 
list-style-type: none;
}

.MainDIV  ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
    padding : 1em;
    }

.MainDIV ul li img
{

    padding: .2em ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5E3;
}

ul li div{display:none; background:white; opacity:.5; position:absolute;}
```

What i am trying to do is shown here.please take a look :[click here](http://laurencekim.com/)

Similar to this page i want to display text over the image whenever someone hover mouse on the image. Can someone please help me out...

Comment: They are only using CSS to accomplich this. There are about 1001 ways to do this.

Comment: And i am displaying 'li' as inline-block so i can't place another DIV block. It will spoil my Html structure.....

Comment: They are using `span` tags to do it, which by default are also inline. But you could also float your `li` tags instead of inline. With `position:absolute;` on the `span` tags you can change them from hidden` to `visible` on hover of the `li`

Comment: What about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/vnZsN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I build up a fiddle with the simpliest way I could think of.

```
$('#hover1').mouseover(function(){
   $('#hoverDiv1').css('opacity', 1)
});


$('#hover1').mouseout(function(){
   $('#hoverDiv1').css('opacity', 0)
});
```

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pP23k/)

Hover effect is not correctly positioned, because "li" needs to be defined.
It is just to show an easy jQuery way.

Best

Comment: You are displaying image whenever mouse enters the DIV block. But i want to display text whenever mouse hover over the image only..

Comment: the effect occures as soon as the mouse hovers over the li which  directly surrounds the image
you can also pass the id to <img... in order to make it work

Comment: swap out #hoverDiv1 with the ID of the image you'll add to the image, then the jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pP23k/1/

please check it out. the effect just occures while hovering the first image.

Comment: Thanks man actually but now the thing is i have to position each text block manually by specifying but how can it be placed over the image independent from left or right of the Html page..Because i have to use this 'ul' in the template(Django). So it should be dynamically done..Not each text hardcoded positioned...

Comment: I found the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263594/how-to-show-text-on-image-when-hovering?rq=1

Comment: great :) 
thought you would like to have it in JS not with css

Comment: oh great! after updating your code now i've found that you already found it!!! anyway my solution is here http://jsfiddle.net/pP23k/2/