# Showing Text When Hovering Over an Image Link

Tags: html, css

I have already looked here ([How to show text on image when hovering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263594/how-to-show-text-on-image-when-hovering)) to find a solution to this problem but it doesnt 100% work... Because the paragraph is located below the image part of the image is not covered when you hover over it. I want the whole image covered by the text when you hover over the image.
(Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/rMhGE/ or below.)

The HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="cube1">

            <a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/busja/busja1209/busja120900010/15099001-detailed-vector-image-of-symbol-of-london--best-known-british-double-decker-bus.jpg">
            <p class="contact">Random Text Here</p></a>
       </div>
</body>
```

The CSS

```
.cube1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
}

.contact {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 386px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    color: #aaa;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.cube1:hover .contact {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: answers already provided. but probably you should get rid of visibility and opacity and use only display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the height from contact. as well as the margin. You also don't need the width value if you're stretching it with the absolute 0 0 0 0 method.

```
.contact {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    color: #aaa;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did I receive a -1?

Answer (score 3):

change the `p {margin:0px}` of the p element
or give the class

```
.contact {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 395px;//change height also to cover it completly
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    color: #aaa;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    margin:0px
}
```

Comment: .contact { margin-top:0px; }

Answer (score 0):

The image has the text over it, I am not sure what you are trying to do here. What do you mean by "covering the image"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set margin on the "p" element to 0 and the "height" to 400:

```
margin:0;
height:400px;
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rMhGE/5/

Comment: And the height for the `p` element should be `400px` to match the image.

Comment: I realized that the absolute position along with 0 for top/bot/left/right was setting the height/width perfectly already, so you can get rid those outright.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rMhGE/6/)

Remove the height from .contact and apply `top: -15px; bottom: -15px;`

Alternatively, the best way, set `margin: 0;` removing height.