# Hiding and revealing text css

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked a hundred times and I have read every last one of them.

I have an image that is also a link. When the image is hovered it shows a new image and I have a small paragraph description I would like to pop up next to the image when the link is hovered over as well. Simple, right?

What i'm doing makes sense to me, and is the answer to this question. What am I doing wrong? This seems very straightforward.

[How to show text on image when hovering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263594/how-to-show-text-on-image-when-hovering)

I will paste my relevant code. Comparing to the posted link answer, I have the class project1 instead of imgWrapper and novelDescrip instead of imgDescription

HTML

```
<div class="project1">
        <a href="#"><img id="novel" src="img/newnovel.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/newnovelblue.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/newnovel.png'" /></a>

        <p class="novelDescrip" >A website for a local musician to market, stream, and distribute music and merchandise.</p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.project1 p {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 20px 15px 0 0;
    float: right;
}

.novelDescrip {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
}

.project1:hover .novelDescrip {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

EDIT

Here is my problem now, the text hides and reveals but the hover is activated anytime my mouse is hovering in the area enclosed by the rectangle I drew on this image. Any ideas on why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Also I should mention, it hides the text, but it does not make it visible

Comment: next to image means? just right of image? or below? if below just remove `position: absolute;` and `float: right;`

Comment: The paragraph should show up to the right of the image

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the the positions. `top:0;left: 0;` with absolute positioned div will always show up on top left corner of the browser. also added `display:inline` for the `novelDescrip` for the div to show-up next to the image.

```
.project1 p {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 20px 15px 0 0;
    float: right;
}

.novelDescrip {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
    display:inline;
}

.project1:hover .novelDescrip {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This works! It makes the paragraph hide and display. However, the area that activates the reveal is far larger than the image. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: If I hover above the image or on the same level as it the paragraph is activated.

Comment: you are using `width: 25%;`. try to change to fixed `width: 150px;` also you can set the `z-index` to a higher value for `p` if it goes behind the any other element.

Answer (score 0):

My be this will solve your problem

```
img {
    height:30%;
    width:30%;
}
.project1 p
{
    width: 65%;
    float: right;
    display:none;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.project1:hover .novelDescrip
{
    display:block;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f55pm/2/)

Comment: This also works to hide and reveal. Thanks! Do you know why the hover area is larger than my image? I posted a screenshot on the original post.

Comment: @zburns12 as hover is set for class of container div, if you want it samller, change the hover for image only

Comment: That makes perfect sense, however, the reveal quits working. It's always hidden. My picture has the id="novel" so wouldn't I just change it to #novel:hover .novelDescrip { display:block; } ? Or did I not do that correctly?