# I''d like to know how to hover over an image and have text show

Tags: css, image, text, hover

here is an example: http://metalabdesign.com/company/

I want it to be simple and NOT use any JS please. I keep getting stuck on knowing the css positioning needed for this. I know i will need to use a hover as well.

Comment: If you can paste in the code you already have, perhaps someone can suggest some tweaks or fixes.

Comment: Something similar to your question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263594/how-to-show-text-on-image-when-hovering

Answer (score 0):

You can set a wrapper div that goes around the image and the caption. Have the caption hidden by default.

Then use a selector to target the caption, but only when the wrapper being hovered.

#### Edit

You want to have the caption positioned `absolutely` and `relative` to the wrapper. This will make it appear on top of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/9eRXG/

#### HTML

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/">
    <figcaption>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

#### CSS

```
figcaption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
    display: block;
}

figure {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out .

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bweuM/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dogs">
    <li class="dog">
        <img class="dog-photo" src="http://placehold.it/200x300" />
        <div class="dog-info">
             <h3 class="info-name">Dog 1</h3>
             <span class="info-title">Founder / CEO</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dog">
        <img class="dog-photo" src="http://placehold.it/200x300" />
        <div class="dog-info">
             <h3 class="info-name">Dog 2</h3>
             <span class="info-title">Founder / CEO</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.dogs{
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.dog {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.dog:hover .dog-info{
    opacity:1;
}
.dog-info {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
}
.info-name,.info-title{
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
.info-name{top:35%;}
.info-title{top:35%;}
```