# How to Get Text To Appear On Top of Image On Hover With CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, when you hover over in image, the opacity gets lighter:

https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1268/

This is correct, but now I also want some link text to appear on top of the image as well. I tried to follow the solution in this example:

[How to show text on image when hovering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263594/how-to-show-text-on-image-when-hovering)

But when I tried this technique, empty space appears below the image, the text doesn't show up on top, and it isn't centered over the image:

https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1269/

I can't seem to figure out how to make the paragraph text appear on top of the box shadow and centered using CSS - any suggestions? If not, then how would this be done with JavaScript? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="row thumbnail-row">
<div class="my-work-image" id="margin-left-image">
    <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/hamburger-thumbnail.jpg"/>        
    <p class="initial-hidden">The Hamburger Collection</p>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
    <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/yoyomoi-thumbnail.jpg"/>   
</div>
<div class="my-work-image"> 
    <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/dogs-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
    <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/gateway-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
    <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/chameleon-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
    <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/adrienne-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
    <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/castaway-thumbnail.jpg"/>
</div>
</div><!--end row-->
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-row {
display: flex;
}
.thumbnail-row div {
position: relative;
}
.thumbnail-row div::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;  
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);
}
.thumbnail-image {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
}

.my-work-image:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}  

/*hidden text*/

.initial-hidden {
visibility: hidden;
text-align: center;
display: inline;
}

.my-work-image:hover .initial-hidden {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 425px) {
.thumbnail-row {
flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes some of the `display` properties.

Also, change the `left: 50%;` in `.img__description_layer` class, if you want the text only shows in the half part of the image.

If you want the `text` to be in the **center of the image**, just remove the css class `.thumbnail-row div::after`

```css
.thumbnail-row {
  display: flex;
}

.thumbnail-row div::after {  /*remove this class to display the text in center of the image*/
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);
}
.thumbnail-image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  }
  
.my-work-image{
  position:relative;
}  

.img__description_layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;    /*change it to 50%, if you want the text only shows in the half part */
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(36, 62, 206, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  text-align:center;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.my-work-image:hover .img__description_layer {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.img__description {
  transition: .2s;
  transform: translateY(1em);
}

.my-work-image:hover .img__description {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
  
@media (max-width: 425px) {
  .thumbnail-row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row thumbnail-row">
    <div class="my-work-image" id="margin-left-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/mNoKbYK.jpg" />
        <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">This image 1 looks super neat.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="my-work-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/8b2sb03.jpg" />
       <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">This image 2 looks super neat.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-work-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ac11pRH.jpg" />
       <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">This image 3 looks super neat.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
  <!--end row-->
</div>
```

Comment: @HappyHands31 I have inspect those images but there is no such `<div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">This image 1 looks super neat.</span>
        </div>` code there. Please add those so that I can try something. 

Also, have you added some new css classes as it is in my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I had changed it back. Let me make the changes again.

Comment: Actually your code is working now and I will go ahead and give you the answer - unfortunately I'm trying to get "My Work" to be above all of the images in its own separate row. Trying to fix this to look like the wireframe: http://i.imgur.com/wrQeuvj.jpg

Comment: **EDIT** - Figured that out - now I've just lost the initial overlay / box shadow. Also how do you center the text horizontally?

Comment: To center align the text, use `text-align:center` in the parent div of the text.

Answer (score 0):

here's what i suggest:

```
/* fade out only the image, not the entire thing */
.my-work-image:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}  

.initial-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    line-height:1em;

    /* use css transform to center vertically and horizontally */
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1272/

Comment: Pawan Kumar answer is more complete. you forgot to give .my-work-image position: relative; which is essential for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

**The transition, background, text color, etc can of course be changed.**

I recommend adding a `filter: blur(2px)` to the image hover (`.hoverable:hover img {}`) to make it look pretty. Just make sure you match it with a transition.

I used **flex** to make the text centered, and a negative positioning on the `<p>` element to get rid of that odd white space at the bottom.

**Edit:** I also fixed the odd space at the bottom without hacks. Simply add `vertical-align: bottom;` to the image.

The display type of the parent (`.hoverable`) can also be channged without causing problems.

**Here is a JSFiddle that has a few more examples: https://jsfiddle.net/spikespaz/p4ogwee2/**

```css
.hoverable {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hoverable img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.hoverable p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

.hoverable:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverable">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/39811/pexels-photo-39811.jpeg" alt="Road Image">
  <p>This text will be shown on hover.</p>
</div>
```