# change of color of the image during the passage of the mouse

Tags: html, image, text, colors

In our site we would like that when the mouse passes over an image, a text is displayed while changing the color of the image as a "transparent white". So that you can understand my request I suggest you if you do not mind to go to the site https://www.ajeance.fr in the menu "**PROJECTS**". You will see that when you move the mouse over the back image it does not completely disappear but has become a little "white" and a text is displayed, if you know what I mean.

Can you please tell me the code in **HTML and/or CSS** that I have to apply to have the same kind of result please? I have tried many codes but without success.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example showing us your code as it is now (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show text on image when hovering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263594/how-to-show-text-on-image-when-hovering)